# Repeating Task in a Service even when the app is closed

Tags: android, service, handler, runnable

I want to call a method at specific interval in a service even when app is closed, Its working fine when app is running even fine when app is in background, But it stopped when I close the app from the background. I want to keep it run even when app is closed how can I achieve it?

I am facing this issue on API 28 below this its working fine.

here is my code.

```
public class ReminderHandlerService extends Service {


private Handler handler;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    handler = new Handler();
    startReminderService();
    return START_STICKY;
    //return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

Runnable runReminder = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {

            Intent reminderServiceIntent = new Intent(ReminderHandlerService.this, ReminderService.class);
            reminderServiceIntent.putExtra("mydata", "this is my data");
            startService(reminderServiceIntent);

        } finally {

            handler.postDelayed(runReminder, 10000);
        }
    }
};

void startReminderService() {
    runReminder.run();
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use something like `WorkManager`, `JobScheduler`, or an alarm via `AlarmManager` in order to execute something event when your app is closed.  If you are targeting newer devices and wish to have backward compatibility, you should look at `WorkManager`:

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/basics

`JobScheduler` and `AlarmManager` are older technologies in Android and will require API specific coding in order to function properly.  `WorkManager` will automatically handle this for you.

Comment: WorkManager is absollutelly unreliable